# Meteor: Deployment Error, MailChimp Undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, mailchimp

I'm having a problem with deploying my meteor app. The log says "Cannot read property 'MailChimp' of undefined." The line of code is:

```
var settings = Meteor.settings.private.MailChimp,
chimp    = new MailChimp( settings.apiKey, { version: '2.0' } ),
listId   = settings.listId;
```

in server/mailchimp.js

I have the mailchimp package on my local server, and the app runs without any problem locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add --settings=settings.json at the end, like

meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com --settings=settings.json